# How do I fix the undefined result I keep getting from this?

Tags: javascript, undefined

So I'm doing the HackerRank superDigit challenge and even though I have the correct value for all the informal test cases, the Output box says that the result is undefined.
I'm not really getting what undefined is all about or how a variable with a value returns as undefined.

```js
function superDigit(n, k) {
    // Write your code here

    var nArr = [];
    
    for(let i = 0; i < n.length; i++)
    {
        nArr.push(n[i]);
    }
    
    console.log('nArr: ' + nArr);
    
    var nComb = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < nArr.length; i++)
    {
        nComb += parseInt(nArr[i]);
    }
    console.log('nComb: ' + nComb);
    
    var nMult = nComb *= k;
    console.log('nMult: ' + nMult);
    console.log('');
    
    if(nMult < 10)
    {
        return nMult;
    }
    else
    {
        superDigit(nMult.toString(),1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is so much wrong with this, that I don't know where to begin. Even the simplest testcase (`superDigit(1)`) runs into a infinite loop.

Comment: @RoToRa just to be sure, did you run it as `superDigit(1)`? Not as `superDigit('1',kValue)`?

Comment: `superDigit(1)` because that's what the task says.

Comment: @RoToRa Please fill me in on what I'm missing...
The parameters for this function is `n` <string> and `k` <number>, as can be seen when the function is defined.
`superDigit('1', kValue)` would be the way you call the function.
When calling `superDigit(1)`, you're not only missing an argument, you're also using a number where you should be using a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to return the `superDigit` result as well. So when calling `superDigit` recursively, add the return statement. I also cleaned up the `console.log` calls a bit so its more readable to me.

```js
function superDigit(n, k) {

    var nArr = [];
    
    for(let i = 0; i < n.length; i++)
    {
        nArr.push(n[i]);
    }
    
    var nComb = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < nArr.length; i++)
    {
        nComb += parseInt(nArr[i]);
    }
    
    var nMult = nComb *= k;
    console.log('nMult:', nMult, 'nArr:', nArr, 'nComb:', nComb);
    
    if(nMult < 10)
    {
        return nMult;
    }
    else
    {
        return superDigit(nMult.toString(),1);
    }
}

document.getElementById('result').innerText = superDigit("200", 20);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p id="result"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! Been running around looking for why I'm getting undefined on variables that have a value, which is why I had all these console logs. Same reason I'm not using operations like `split()` here either. Your description gives so much more meaning to `return` for me. Thank you, again!